# Why is this scope causing recusion in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`scope :name, -> (name){ where "lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{name.downcase}%"}`

I have a model with a `name` property.  When I query that property directly, everything works fine.  When I try to dry it up with the above scope, I start getting stack level errors -- somehow, that scope is causing recursion even on a `Client.where(true)` statement.  Even if I change it from `name` to `number`, on the off chance I'm somehow conflicting with a built-in method, it doesn't work.  What am I overlooking?

Relevant model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :name, -> (name){ where "lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{name.downcase}%"}
end
```

with schema:

```
create_table "clients", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "number"
  t.string   "email",            null: false
  # Other columns omitted for brevity, nothing unusual or odd about them.
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your scope is named `name`.  The `name` method normally returns the class name.  Some Rails code makes use of the `name` method, such as the `parent_name` method in the [introspection module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb):

```
def parent_name
  if defined? @parent_name
    @parent_name
  else
    @parent_name = name =~ /::[^:]+\Z/ ? $`.freeze : nil  # This line calls the "name" method
  end
end
```

`parent_name` can take a class name like `Admin::User` and return `Admin`.

Methods like `parent_name` are used by core functions like `compute_table_name` in the [ModelSchema](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb).  The `compute_table_name` logic and the `current_scope` logic can get mixed up in a loop when a scope is named `name`.  This leads to `stack level too deep` errors.

You can avoid this by altering your scope to something like:

```
scope :by_name, ->(name) { where "lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{name.downcase}%" }
```